# Thymeleaf Server-relative URL is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm uploading some images in a folder that is outside of my webapp context. Now, I need to display those images, I tried this:

```
 <img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" th:src="@{~/my-server-path/Logo-Free.jpg}" alt="Logo"/>
```

This is not working because is looking for the image in localhost:8080/my-server-path/Logo-Free.jpg.

what I need is to find the image in /my-server-path/Logo-Free.jpg.

I also tried something like this:

```
<img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" th:src="@{file:///my-server-path/Logo-Free.jpg}" alt="Logo"/>
```

but is not working, does anybody could give me a suggestion about how to display a image that is located in my server?

Comment: What is the path to this HTML page on the server? `localhost:8080/my-server-path/Logo-Free.jpg` looks like the right URL.

Comment: The thing is that the Logo-Free.jpg is outside of my webapp context, let's say that my image is located into ~/Users/someuser/images/Logo-Free.jpg. What I'm trying to do is to display that image using my server-relative URL

Comment: That's... not how server-relative URLs work. (And annoyingly, if you're accessing your application over HTTP, the browser will block `file:` URLs for security reasons.)

Comment: ok, do you have a suggestion about how to achieve something like this?, or this is not possible, I was thinking to copy the image into the webapp context

Comment: I suppose you could create a resource mapping in your configuration that pointed to local locations, then let the Spring resource handler serve the files over HTTP to the browser.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a mvc resource mapping in your dispatcher-servlet like below:-

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/home/images/" />
```

and then refer the url like below:-

```
<img class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" th:src="@{file:///my-server-path/images/Logo-Free.jpg}" alt="Logo"/>
```